# WORKDAY.INTL formula not working as intended

Tags: excel, excel-formula, wps

[image]

So i have this table shown above. `K3` represents the date (manually entered) and `L1` represents the lead time.

**The conditions the result has to follow is shown below**

1. Days that should be included are Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Saturday and Sunday. (Leaving out Friday as non working day)
2. The Holidays should not be included `=holidays!A2:A9`

the formula in `L3` is

```
=WORKDAY.INTL(K4, L2, "0111101", holidays!A2:A9)
```

The list of holidays are shown in the table below.

[image]

As you can see, the result in `L3` is `2nd March` instead of `29th February`. As this date does not fall on the holiday list and is not a Friday. Could someone help me with this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your formula is working correctly as intended, because in `WORKDAY.INTL()` function `1` represents a non-workday and `0` represents a workday. That said, `29th Feb'24` is `Thursday` and you have made it non workin day, hence in your formula: only `Monday` and `Saturday` are workdays rest are non workdays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WORKDAY.INTL()` is working as intended.

In `WORKDAY.INTL()` function `1` represents a `non-workday` and `0` represents a `workday`. That said, `29th Feb'24` is `Thursday` and you have made it `non-working day`, hence in your formula: only `Monday` and `Saturday` are `workdays` rest are `non workdays`. Read `MSFT` Documentations [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/workday-intl-function-a378391c-9ba7-4678-8a39-39611a9bf81d).

[image]

---

**What has been used:**

```
=WORKDAY.INTL(B3,1,"0111101",Holidays[[Date]:[Date]])
```

---

**What needs to be used:**

[image]

---

```
=WORKDAY.INTL(B3,1,"0000100",Holidays[[Date]:[Date]])
```

---

Or, instead of using `"0000100"` use `16`

```
=WORKDAY.INTL(B3,1,16,Holidays[[Date]:[Date]])
```

---

In context of your OP, the formula will be:

```
=WORKDAY.INTL(K4, L2, "0000100", holidays!A2:A9)
```

---

The following grid may help to understand as well:

[image]

---